# Passing int&& to f(int&&)

Tags: c++, c++11

What is exactly happening here? Why is this an error?

```
void f(int &&);

int && i = 5;

f(i);
```

Isn't it a bit counterintuitive?

I would expect `i` to be a rvalue reference, and so be able to pass it to `f()`. But I get an error;

> no known conversion from `int` to `int &&`

So I guess `i` is not an rvalue reference after declaration?

Comment: What are you hoping will happen? What are you trying to do? What do you think `&&` means in this context?

Comment: @Galik, I added some more comments to my question.

Comment: Use `std::move()` to get an rvalue reference.

Comment: Thanks @JameyD . What I find confusing is that a declare something of type X, and then I pass it to a function accepting X, but it does not work. I guess "i" is not a rvalue reference (even if I write &&) because it has a name, and I can use it to assign things to it, but still wanted to know what is really happening under the hood.

Comment: _"I guess "i" is not a rvalue reference"_ That's not true, `i` **is** an rvalue-reference, but that describes what it binds to, not what kind of value category it has. Its value category is lvalue.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28483250/1782465

Comment: Thanks @JonathanWakely that makes sense

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a basic distinction here between *is a* and *binds a*. For example:

```
void f(int &&);
```

declares a function accepting a parameter that can only be initialized with an rvalue reference to a (type convertible to) `int`.

```
int && i = 5;
```

declares an lvalue that can only be initialized with an rvalue reference to a (type convertible to) `int`. Thus, in simple terms,

```
f(i);
```

tries to pass an lvalue reference to an `int` to a function accepting only rvalue references to an `int`. So it doesn't compile.

To tell the compiler to cast an lvalue to an rvalue, thereby utilizing *move constructors* where applicable (though not in the case of an `int`), you can use `std::move()`.

```
f(std::move(i));
```

Comment: I would add information about `std::move` in this case.

Comment: @Zereges Good idea. Added.

Comment: This is **almost** an excellent answer, but slightly inaccurate. _"declares an lvalue that can only be assigned an rvalue reference to an int."_  No, it cannot be "assigned" anything, certainly not an rvalue reference (because assigning to a reference actually assigns to the thing it is bound to, but this is initialization not assignment). It declares an lvalue, `i`, of rvalue-reference type, that can only be **initialized** with an rvalue (not an rvalue-reference, an rvalue).

Comment: _"To force the compiler to treat lvalue references as rvalue references"_ should be "To force the compiler to treat lvalues as rvalues", or even better, "To tell the compiler to cast an lvalue to an rvalue".

Comment: @Yam `std::forward` would do, too, wouldn't it?

Comment: @LogicStuff, if you forward as an rvalue, yes, but that's pointless here. If you know you want an rvalue, use `std::move`. If you want to forward something as either lvalue or rvalue, depending on its original value category, use `std::forward`. It's completely pointless to write `std::forward<int>(i)` instead of `std::move(i)`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Re assignment point, doh! Thanks, will edit. Re rest of stuff: ditto.

Comment: In the declaration `int && i = 5;`, `i` is an rvalue reference, **not** an lvalue reference, and `5` is an _rvalue_ of type `int`, **not** an rvalue reference.

Comment: I think you confused l/rvalue references with l/rvalues. They are distinct concepts.

Comment: @cpplearner It's a bit confusing, but `i` itself is actually an lvalue. For instance, you can take its address. This was the main confusion I was trying to sort out.

Comment: @YamMarcovic Yes, `i` is an lvalue **and an rvalue reference**.

Comment: @cpplearner See [Value Categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) `Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression`

Answer (score 30):

I see why you are confused. The thing to remember is that whenever you have a variable name, you have an *l-value*.

So when you say:

```
int i = 0; // lvalue (has a name i)
```

And also

```
int&& i = 0; // lvalue (has a name i)
```

So what is the difference?

The `int&&` can only bind to an *r-value* so:

```
int n = 0;
int i = n; // legal
```

**BUT**

```
int n = 0;
int&& i = n; // BAD!! n is not an r-value
```

**However**

```
int&& i = 5; // GOOD!! 5 is an r-value
```

So when passing `i` to `f()` in this example you are passing an *l-value*, not an *r-value*:

```
void f(int &&);

int&& i = 5; // i is an l-value

f(i); // won't accept l-value
```

The situation is actually a little more complicated than I have presented here. If you are interested in a fuller explanation then this reference is quite thorough: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: I think it's a great answer. The only slight thing I'd suggest is, perhaps make it a bit more clear in that first sentence, because often `this` can be thought of as a variable (though it isn't really), but then `this` is a prvalue. Can you think of any good way to address this point, or if it's really relevant after all?

Comment: @YamMarcovic I know the situation can be a little more complicated but I think for learning purposes it is better to present what is simple and relevant to the example the OP is trying to understand. What I will do is add a link for further information.

Comment: @Galik Sounds reasonable. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Does it have a name?
Is it addressable?

If the answer to both is "yes", it's a L-Value.

In this snippet: `i` has a name, `i` has an address (you can write `&i`), so it's a l-value.

`f(&&)` gets r-value-reference as a parameter, so you need to turn l-value to r-value reference, which can be done with `std::move`.

```
f(std::move(i));
```

Comment: Note: there are also some lvalues which don't have names.  Also, "Is it addressable" is a circular definition. By "addressable", I assume you mean, "can unary `&` be applied to it?"; however the definition of unary `&` includes that it can be applied to lvalues only!