# Rvalue references and std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11

1. Is there any difference between `int&& i = 42;` and `int i = 42;` ?
2. Regarding `std::forward`, I read online that "if arg is an lvalue reference, the function returns arg without modifying its type." However the following code:

```
void f(int& k)
{
    std::cout << "f(int&) " << k << std::endl;
}

void f(int&& k)
{
    std::cout << "f(int&&) " << k << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 42;
    int& j = i;
    int&& k = 42;

    f(i);
    f(j);
    f(k);

    f(std::forward<int>(i));
    f(std::forward<int>(j));
    f(std::forward<int>(k));
    return 0;
}
```

prints out

```
f(int&) 42
f(int&) 42
f(int&) 42
f(int&&) 42
f(int&&) 42
f(int&&) 42
```

I'm wondering why the 4th and 5th lines aren't `f(int&) 42`, as per the quote I mentioned above.

Comment: `std::forward` is meant to be used with template argument that was deduced.

Comment: Does this mean that I should never call `std::forward` inside a function that is neither a template function nor a template class member function?

Comment: Because you use `std::forward<int>`, making it return `int &&`. Try `std::forward<int &>` and you'll get `f(int&)`. Basically, it's `static_cast<T&&>`, with `T`  being `int` in your case. I'm not implying such usage of `std::forward<T>` makes sense, by the way.

Comment: It's all [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward). Using `std::forward<TypeNotDeducedFromForwardingReference>` does not make sense because it's the very template parameter that says whether `std::forward` will return rvalue or lvalue. In this case `std::forward<int>(i)` is equivalent to `std::move(i)` and `std::forward<int&>(i)` is equivalent to `i`.

Comment: @Pippin : Related link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314093/passing-int-to-fint/35314267

Comment: Your quote appears to come from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/forward/. cplusplus.com is not a good reference. Please consider using alternatives, for instance cppreference.com already linked in a comment and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is there any difference between int&& i = 42; and int i = 42; ?

Yes. Former variable is an rvalue reference to `int` which is bound to a temporary `int` object. Latter variable is an `int` object. The former is an unnecessarily convoluted way to refer to an object.

No, there is no difference in the context of 2. part of your question.

> 2. ... "if arg is an lvalue reference, the function returns arg without modifying its type." ...

The quote isn't exactly accurate by itself. It makes an assumption, that the template argument of `forward` was deduced from the type of `arg`. You didn't use a deduced type, but instead `int` which would not have been deduced from an lvalue reference.

> I'm wondering why the 4th and 5th lines aren't `f(int&) 42`

`int` is not an lvalue reference, so the quote does not apply to 4th line.

Let us consider, what exatly does `std::forward` do? It does this:

```
Returns: static_cast<T&&>(t).
```

Now, if `T` is `int`, then it does `static_cast<int&&>(t)`, so the result type is an rvalue reference, regardless of the type of `t`. If you use a non-lvalue-reference as the type argument to `std::forward`, it behaves exactly like a `std::move`.

To comply with the assumptions of the quote, you could have done:

```
f(std::forward<decltype(i)>(i));
f(std::forward<decltype(j)>(j));
f(std::forward<decltype(k)>(k));
```

With this, the output is:

```
f(int&&) 42
f(int&) 42
f(int&&) 42
```

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused. Would you mind showing a code where `i` and `k` produce different results?

Comment: @Pippin I didn't say they produce different results. I answered the question `Is there any difference between`. There can be a difference between things, even if they behave the same in some regard.

Comment: @Pippin the only code giving different results in 1. is `decltype(i)`

Answer (score 0):

I would say the function is pretty well explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward). When in a context where you can have universal references (T&& where T is deduced for that context), forward ensures that you relay the arguments with the same characteristics of l/r-valueness.