# Should std::move be used on members when initializing them in the constructor?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to fully understand move semantics, but I have one question, as different examples show different things.  Say we have a class Foo that has a string member str_. To define the move constructor, should I define it like this:

```
Foo(Foo&& foo) : str_(foo.str_) { }
```

or this:

```
Foo(Foo&& foo) : str_(std::move(foo.str_)) { }
```

Also, would I need to set the members of the object i am moving from to a blank value? How would I do so without constructing another string, essentially nullifying the expense saved by using a move constructor in the first place?

Comment: *set the members to a blank value?* What do you mean? You're setting the value of `str_` by moving `foo.str_` into it.

Comment: @Rakete1111 The string is only an example, what if it was a very large object?

Comment: @DeiDei Sorry, I worded that poorly. I am referring to the members of the object I am moving from.

Comment: This question has some good explanations about r-value references. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314093/passing-int-to-fint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a move constructor (or move assignment operator), you need to use `std::move()` when moving individual members (or at least, on non-POD members, since "moving" a POD type is the same as copying it).

In `Foo&& foo`, `foo` is an rvalue reference, but `foo.str_` is not. If you call `str_(foo.str_)` in your move constructor (or `str_ = foo.str_` in your move assignment operator), it will call the string's copy constructor (or copy assignment operator). So you need to cast `foo.str_` to an rvalue reference via `std::move()` in order to invoke the string's move constructor (or move assignment operator).

A move constructor (and move assignment operator) is responsible for leaving the moved-from object in an unspecified but valid state, so its destructor will not fail.  In the case of moving the `foo.str_` member, the string's move constructor (or move assignment operator) will reset `foo.str_` to an empty string for you, you do not need to reset it manually.

Comment: Thank you! So I should use move as long as the member type has a move constructor?

Comment: Are you sure `std::string` in case of short string optimization, it sounds acceptable that a simple copy occurs.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string indicates valid but unspecified state. So to have it empty, you have to call `clear()`

Comment: `foo` is declared as an *r-value reference* but that only determines what it can bind to. Once it is bound it is a normal *l-value reference* (because it has a name). That is why you need to re-apply `std::move`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the second approach.

You do not have to do anything to the `string` you move from, because this is handled by `string`'s move constructor.  The latter is invoked by the `move()` call.

The same goes for your own classes, anything you want to `move()` should have a move constructor.  For instance, if your class has a pointer member, your move constructor could/should assign `nullptr` to that member in the object you `move()` from.