# How reference deduce works?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, effective-c++, forward-reference

May be duplicated to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483250/rvalue-reference-is-treated-as-an-lvalue).

I read [Effective Modern C++](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/effective-modern-c/9781491908419/titlepage01.html). Under `Item 1`, I found a case for universal reference:[image]

For the last example `f(27);` I did a test under VS2013.

```
void process(int& x)
{
    std::cout << "int&" << std::endl;
}
void process(int&& x)
{
    std::cout << "int&&" << std::endl;
}
template<typename T>
void f(T&& param)
{
    std::cout << "------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    if (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
    {
        std::cout << "T is lvalue reference" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
    {
        std::cout << "T is rvalue reference" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "T is NOT lvalue reference" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "param is: " << typeid(param).name() << std::endl;

    process(std::forward<T>(param));
    process(param);
}
int getINT()
{
    int x = 10;
    return x;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    f(10);
    f(getINT());

    return 0;

}
```

Here is the output:

```
------------------------------------------------
T is NOT lvalue reference
param is: int
int&&
int&
------------------------------------------------
T is NOT lvalue reference
param is: int
int&&
int&
```

I found that within the template function, without `std::forward<T>(param)`, `process(int& x)` will be called but according to the book, the type for `param` should be rvalue reference, so `process(int&& x)` should be called. But this is not the case. **Is it I misunderstand something?**

Here is the forwarding reference I found from other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward):
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rvalue Reference is Treated as an Lvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483250/rvalue-reference-is-treated-as-an-lvalue)

Comment: Your question has a lot in it, but I'm pretty sure it is "why is an rvalue reference treated as an lvalue?"

Comment: Thank you, I will close my question

Comment: "rvalue reference" means that it binds to rvalues, not that its name is an rvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing types with [value categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). As a named parameter, `param` is an lvalue, then for `process(param);` `process(int& x)` will be called.

That's why we should use [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) with [forwarding reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references); `std::forward<T>(param)` converts `param` to rvalue for this case, then `process(int&& x)` will be called (as expected).

Comment: So you mean that if I have `int&& x = 10;`, then what type is `x`? It is not rvalue reference?

Comment: @sflee Its type is `int&&`, but it's an lvalue. Lvalue can't be bound to rvalue-reference, then `process(int&& x)` won't be selected when being called.

Comment: @songyuanyao its type is `int` and its value category is "lvalue"

Comment: @M.M For `int&& x` shouldn't the type be `int&&` (i.e. rvalue-reference to `int`) ?

Comment: The expression `x` has type `int` . Expressions never have reference type.  If talking about the entity `x` I tend to say "the declared type of `x` is `int&&`" ; if you don't make this distinction then it is ambiguous to talk about "the type of `x`"

Comment: @M.M I got what you mean. Here I think saying "the declared type of `x` is `int&&` but its value category is lvalue" should be most clear to OP.

Comment: @songyuanyao the entity `x` doesn't have a value category though - only expressions have value categories.

Comment: @M.M Okay, then it would be "even the declared type of `x` is `int&&` but when used as expression its value category is lvalue".

Comment: Thank you very much songyuanyao and M.M