# Why rvalue reference as return type can't be initialization of non-const reference?

Tags: c++, return-type, rvalue-reference, rvalue, lvalue

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483250/rvalue-reference-is-treated-as-an-lvalue) question and I know that an rvalue referenec is an lvalue.

However, for this code, example 1,

```
int &&fun() {
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int &a = fun();
}
```

When I compile it:

```
 error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'
```

So the C++ compiler tells me the return type of `fun` is an rvalue.

How does a rvalue reference become an rvalue?

I think the compiler should treat lvalue reference and rvalue reference by the same way, but this code, example 2,

```
int & fun(){
    int b;
    return b;
}
int main(){
    int & a=fun();
}
```

can be compiled (nevertheless, I get a warning).

I think maybe the return type of `fun` has changed at some point.

Trying to compile example 3:

```
int &&fun() {
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    decltype(fun()) b = 1;
}
```

it compiles successfully. So I can say the return type of `fun` is really an rvalue reference.

So, why does an rvalue reference become an rvalue?

Here is example 4:

```
int &&a = 1;
int &b = a;
```

It compiles and tells us an rvalue reference can be bound to an lvalue reference.

Now, what about those two questions:

1. In example 1, is `fun()` an rvalue?
2. In example 1, is `fun()` an rvalue reference?

Example 3 tells us `fun()` is an rvalue reference,and example 4 tells us an rvalue reference can be bound to an lvalue reference (both const and non-const). Then why can't the `fun()` from example 1 be bound to an lvalue reference?

Example 4 also indicates that an rvalue reference is an lvalue, but the compilation error in example 1 tells us that `fun()` there, which is proved to be an rvalue reference in example 3, is an rvalue. So, is an rvalue reference lvalue or rvalue?

If the cause is that `fun()` is just an expression, which exists temporarily and will die right away, why is `fun()` from example 2 not be regarded an rvalue while it is also just an expression without a name? What difference is there between a function expression of a function returning an lvalue reference and an rvalue reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that an rvalue reference is an lvalue.

You're talking about two different things: type and [value category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). e.g.

```
int&& ri = 0; // ri's type is rvalue reference (to int)
              // ri's value category is lvalue; it's a named variable.
```

Given your 1st sample, what `fun()` returns is an xvalue, which belongs to rvalues.

> The following expressions are xvalue expressions:
>
> - a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object, such as `std::move(x)`;

then,

```
int &a = fun(); // fails; lvalue-reference can't bind to rvalue
```

In the 2nd sample, what `fun()` returns is an lvalue,

> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is lvalue reference, such as `std::getline(std::cin, str)`,
>   `std::cout << 1`, `str1 = str2`, or `++it`;

then

```
int & a=fun(); // fine; lvalue-reference could bind to lvalue
```

In the 3rd sample,

```
decltype(fun()) b = 1; // the return type of fun() is rvalue-reference;
                       // this has nothing to do with the value category of its return value
                       // b's type is rvalue-reference too, btw its value category is lvalue
```

In the 4th sample,

```
int &&a = 1; // fine; rvalue-reference could bind to rvalue
             // a's type is rvalue-reference, its value category is lvalue
int &b = a;  // fine; lvalue-reference could bind to lvalue
             // b's type is lvalue-reference, its value category is lvalue
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, value category is a property of **expression**, not of **variable**.

Answer (score 1):

Non-const references cannot bind to rvalues, it's as simple as that.

```
int & a=fun();
```

does not work because `a` is a non-const reference and `fun()` is an rvalue expression.
In the second case, `fun()` returns a non-const lvalue reference, which can bind to another non-const reference, of course.

```
decltype(fun()) b=1;
```

works because `decltype(fun())` is `int &&` and can thus bind to the integer literal `1`.

---

> In example 1, is `fun()` an rvalue?

Yes.

> In example 2, is `fun()` an rvalue reference?

No, it's an lvalue reference.

> Example 3 tells us that `fun()` is an rvalue reference and example 4 tells us an rvalue
>   reference can be bound to an lvalue reference (both const and
>   non-const). Then why can't `fun()` from example 1 be bound to an lvalue
>   reference?

Because the function `fun` returns an rvalue reference, but `fun()` itself is an *rvalue expression*. `fun()` is an rvalue.

> Example 4 also indicates that an rvalue reference is an lvalue, but the
>   compilation error in example 1 tells us that `fun()` there, which is proved to be
>   an rvalue reference in example 3, is an rvalue. So, is an rvalue reference lvalue
>   or rvalue?

An rvalue reference is an lvalue.

> If the cause is that `fun()` is just an expression, which exists
>   temporarily and will die right away, why is the `fun()` in example 2 not
>   regarded an rvalue while it is also just an expression without
>   a name? What difference is there between a function expression of a function returning an lvalue reference and an rvalue reference?

Because in example 2, `fun()` is an lvalue. From N4296, §3.10/1.1:

> [...] the result of calling a function whose return type is an lvalue
>   reference is an lvalue.

---

Regarding the warning you get for example 2, you should show the exact message. It's probably just because you return a reference to a local variable, though. Local variables have limited lifetime, so referencing them beyond their lifetime is undefined behavior, hence the warning.

Comment: I think you have got a conflict that **an rvalue reference is rvalue**(From Ex 1 and Ex 3),which is diagreed with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483250/rvalue-reference-is-treated-as-an-lvalue. BTW,I've clarified my questions more detailedly.Thanks.:)

Comment: @user482214 Nowhere did I mention that an rvalue reference is an rvalue. I'm going to update my answer in accordance to your edit.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this code exhibits undefined behavior:

```
int && fun(){
    return 1;
}
```

Here you're returning a dangling reference to `1`, which goes out of scope.

> ***How does a rvalue reference become an rvalue?***

In order to understand this it's good to view references not as another syntax for pointers, but as another *name* for some already existing object.

Then it's good to go over reference initialization rules:

The [first reference initialization rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.ref#5.1) states that a reference may be initialized ("bound") to a *reference-compatible* value. That means

- `int&` can bind to `int&`
- `int&&` can bind to `int&&`
- `const int&` can bind to `int&`

In this case the actual referred-to *value* of the right-hand side is not retrieved, but is directly bound to the new reference.
Note that `int&` is not compatible with `int&&`, these are distinct types.

The [second reference initialization rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.ref#5.2) states that a `const` lvalue reference (`const int&`) and an rvalue reference (`int&&`) may bind to:

- xvalue or prvalue
- as the last resort to anything else

In case of the latter the reference binds to the *result* of the expression. In the case of `const int& x = fun()`, the result of calling `fun()` will first be "materialized" (retrieved), and then its *value* will be bound to the reference.

But for that to happen, the lvalue reference must be `const`. That's why the error states that a non-`const` `int&` cannot bind to `int`, because `int` is the result of evaluating `fun()`.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that the value category of an expression does not only depend on its type, e.g.

```
int&& a = 1;
int&& fun();
// int&& ri = a; // ill-formed, the expression a is of type int&&, but is an lvalue
int&& ri = fun(); // ok, the expression fun() is of type int&&, and is also an rvalue
```

---

In addition, as rustyx pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50546446/5376789), the function definition

```
int && fun(){
    return 1;
}
```

would probably result in undefined behavior, because the temporary object will be destroyed immediately after the execution of the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing `rvalue` and `rvalue reference`. In your first example

```
int && fun(){
    // 1 is an rvalue so it can be bound to an rvalue reference
    // this will produce undefined behavior though because you
    // a returning a dangling reference to an temporary that will
    // go out of scope at the end of this function
    return 1;
}
int main(){
    // you are trying to take a reference to a temporary object.
    // this is (deliberately) not valid
    int & a=fun();

    // One legal way of doing this is by declaring your reference const:
    const int& b = fun(); 
    // because this extends the lifetime of the temporary object returned
    // by fun() to match the lifetime of the reference.
}
```

In your second example:

```
int & fun(){
    // you have allocated an new int in the free store so the 
    // lifetime of this int is until the main exits. The return
    // type here is an lvalue that can be safely bound to an 
    // lvalue reference
    return *(new int);
}
int main(){
    // binding lvalue reference to lvalue this is ok
    int & a=fun();
}
```

In your third example

```
int && fun(){
    // 1 is an rvalue and can be bound to an rvalue reference
    return 1;
}
int main(){
    // decltype(fun()) is equal to int&& so it's ok to bind
    // an rvalue reference to an rvalue
    decltype(fun()) b=1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much that I changed my Ex 2 and add Ex 4.Firstly,I think In Ex 2 I can return a reference of a int with its lifetime only in the function scope,so it is also a temporary object,the same as the one in Ex 1.Secondly,I think Ex 3 tells us the return type of the function is an rvalue reference,which is an lvalue and can be bound to an lvalue reference(disagreed with Ex 1).

Comment: @user482214 in ex2 by using `new` you are extending the life of that value beyond the scope of the function, so if you don't `delete` that value, you will get a so-called `memory leak`. In example 4, `a` is an lvalue, becuase it has a name and I can take its address so it's ok to bind a lvalue reference `b` to an lvalue (int&& a) that happens to be a rvalue reference. If something happens to the temporary being referenced by `a`, `b` still holds a valid reference to `a` in the current scope.