# What's the difference between an ordinary rvalue reference and one returned by std::forward?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, value-categories

I can't do this:

```
int &&q = 7;
int &&r = q; 
//Error Message:
//cannot convert from 'int' to 'int &&'
//You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
```

If I understand correctly, when initializing an rvalue reference, there's a temporary variable got initialized too. So `int &&q = 7;` can be considered as:

```
int temp = 7;
int &&q = temp;
```

And when using a reference on the right side, I am actually using the referee. So `int &&r = q;` can be considered as:

```
int &&r = temp;  //bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference, cause error, understandable
```

So above is how I understand the compiler error occurs.

---

Why adding `std::forward` can solve that?

```
int &&q = 7;
int &&r = std::forward<int>(q);
```

I know the `std::forward` always returns an rvalue reference, how is the reference returned by `std::forward` different from `int&&q`?

Comment: Equivalent is not the same as identical. Hard coded values are not treated as regular variables

Comment: Don't think I could explain it better than Scott, so check out this:
https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: As others have hinted, `int &&r = std::move(q);` would be the more idiomatic way to do the cast in this case.  `std::forward` is meant for use in "perfect forwarding" to pass on parameters which have template types such as `template <typename T> void f(T&& x)` or `template <typename... T> void f(T&&... x)`

Comment: Another possible surprise: `decltype(q)` is equivalent to `int&&` while `decltype((q))` is equivalent to `int&`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> how is the reference returned by `std::forward` different from `int&&q` ?

Their [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) are different. And note that types and value categories are different things.

`q` is a named variable, it's qualified as [lvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue), so it can't be bound to rvalue reference.

(emphasis mine)

> the name of a variable, a function, a template parameter object (since C++20), or a data member, regardless of type, such as `std::cin` or `std::endl`. **Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression;**

While rvalue reference returned from function is qualified as [xvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue), which belongs to [rvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue).

> a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object, such as `std::move(x)`;

Comment: Damn, this is so hard. I understand a little bit more now, thank you again, yuanyao.

Comment: @Rick Try to always consider types and value categories separately, it'll become more clear.

Answer (score 11):

The difference between the expressions `q` and `std::forward<int>(q)` is that the former is an lvalue, while the latter is an rvalue (of fundamental category xvalue).

I've addressed similar concerns in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28483352/1782465): the point is that `q` as an expression is an *lvalue*, because it has a name. `std::forward<int>(q)` (or the equivalent `std::move(q)`) are expressions which don't have names, and since they return (unnamed) rvalue references, they are xvalues, which is a subcategory of rvalue and can thus bind to an rvalue reference.