# decltype(auto) function return type does not deduce && types

Tags: c++

If a function returns decltype(auto) and it returns a local variable of type int&&, why does the return type is int&?

If I cast the variable to its own type, then the return type is what I expect (int&&)

```
#include <utility>

namespace{
    auto i = 5;
    auto j = 5;

    decltype(auto) foo1(){
        int&& ret = std::move(i);
        return ret;
    }

    decltype(auto) foo2(){
        int&& ret = std::move(j);
        return static_cast<decltype(ret)>(ret);
    }
}

int main(){
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(foo1()),int&>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(foo2()),int&&>);
}
```

Comment: A named rvalue reference (such as `ret`) [is an lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28483250/1782465).

Comment: Clang actually reject the code: https://godbolt.org/z/g_FIOf

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in GCC. Since `decltype(ret)` is `int&&`, `foo1` should have return type `int&&`. However, this immediately renders `foo1` ill-formed, since a function that returns `int&&` cannot have its return value initialized from `ret`, which is an lvalue (you would need `std::move` to make it work properly). Note that Clang gets this right (see link in comments to the question).