# Reason to use std::move on rvalue reference parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, value-categories

I was reading a book about data structure implemented in C++, I dont understand a code snippet， it's part of vector class

```
void push_back(object &&x) {
        //do something
        objects[size++] = std::move(x);
    }
```

I know that `std::move` return a rvalue reference of the object, but the `push_back` member function already has rvalue reference `x` as parameter, isn't the `std::move` here unnecessary？

Another question is if we have a rvalue reference of a class object, we still need to use `std::move` on its member if we want to call move instead of copy right? like the code below:

```
A& operator=(A&& other) {
     member = std::move(other.member);
     return *this;
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483250/rvalue-reference-is-treated-as-an-lvalue

Comment: OT: What book was that? `objects[size++] = std::move(x);` requires a valid object of vector's value type at `&objects[size]`, which is not how `push_back` should work. Vectors typically use placement new (allocator's `construct` generally) to create a new object there, not an assignment operator. Also note that if the assignment throws (by throwing move assignment op. or copy assignment op.), then, the `size` will be incremented and the state of the vector will be incorrect. Better to do `size++;` at the next line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> isn't the std::move here unnecessary？

No. Types and [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) are different things.

(emphasis mine)

> Each C++ expression (an operator with its operands, a literal, a variable name, etc.) is characterized by **two independent properties: a *type* and a *value category***.
>
> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> the name of a variable, a function, a template parameter object (since
>   C++20), or a data member, regardless of type, such as std::cin or
>   std::endl. **Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the
>   expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression**;

`std::move` converts lvalue to rvalue (xvalue). As a named variable, `x` is an lvalue, `std::move` converts it to rvalue in `objects[size++] = std::move(x);` then the move assignment operator is supposed to be used. Otherwise, copy assignment operator will be used instead; lvalue can't be bound to rvalue reference.

> we still need to use `std::move` on its member if we want to call move instead of copy right?

Yes, same reason as above.

Answer (score 6):

`x` has a name, thus it's an lvalue inside the function. The rvalue reference was bound to the lvalue `x`. `std::move` casts it back to the rvalue that was passed in.