# Passing an rvalue to a function

Tags: c++, rvalue

I read a lot of information about rvalue links, I understood everything, but I met this example:

```
template<class T, class Arg>
T* make_raw_ptr(Arg &&arg)
{
    return new T(arg);
};
```

If you pass rvalue to the `make_raw_ptr` function without using the my_forward function, when using new T, there will be a copy constructor, not a move constructor. I understand that `arg` will be lvalue, despite the fact that it is an rvalue reference, but I have one question. Why make a `static_cast` `arg` to an rvalue link when it is already an rvalue link, while using a `static_cast<A&&>` to arg, the move constructor will be called?

Comment: That's not an "rvalue link" ; it's a *forwarding* reference because it is in a deduced context. I think you'll find [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) highly informative.

Comment: I think I figure it out... Rvalue reference is lvalue because it is reference and we can imagine it as "const Arg &arg = rvalue", but without const ofc. In this case, there is copy constuctor will be called, not move. Am I right? @WhozCraig

Comment: @malloc this is just a mental model, but in general: if it is has a name, it's an lvalue, unless explicitly cast to rvalue. As for the example you gave, `arg` is neither  lvalue nor rvalue reference, it's a forwarding reference which is deduced at compile time to either r- or l- value one.

Comment: @alagner why isn't arg lvalue? [Here](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html) is said "An rvalue reference behaves just like an lvalue reference except that it can bind to a temporary". It explains why copy constructor will be called in my example.

Comment: @malloc it's been answered already: it's a template argument deduced at compile time, so it's a [forwarding reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996187/c-forwarding-reference-and-r-value-reference) (from caller's perspective). Inside the function `make_raw_ptr` it generally is an lvalue as (to put it simply) it has a name. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58761212/4885321) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arg` itself is an expression that represents an object referred to by `arg` and its value category is *lvalue*. It doesn't matter what the type of `arg` actually is. A name of a variable / function parameter itself is always an lvalue expression.

`static_cast<A&&>(arg)` is an expression that represents the very same object as `arg`, but its category is *rvalue* (and *xvalue*). When you use this expression as the constructor argument, the move constructor will be preferred. The same effect is with `std::move(arg)`.