# Why when r-value reference is being assigned to is considered as an l-value reference?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code: ([compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/h6EUX3AcI32Ak0sl))

```
void f(int&&) {}

template<class T>
void s(T&& value)
{
    using rv_ref = decay_t<T>&&;

    static_assert( is_same_v<decltype(value), rv_ref> );

    f(static_cast<rv_ref>(value)); // ok, but we've checked `value` is already of this type
    //f(value); // error: no matching function
}

int main()
{
    s(9);
}
```

What makes me flinch is the fact that even though the type of `value` is `int&&`, when it's being used as a value [and not an expression(as with `decltype`)], it suddenly becomes an l-value.

How is this explained to make sense?

Comment: Anything that has a name is an lvalue

Comment: I think the `value` here is a universal reference ([forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)).

Comment: @JesperJuhl, then it would be rational for `value` to have type `int&` [and not `int&&`]. And everything would still work as expected (right?) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write this:

> even though the type of `value` is int&&, when it's being used as a value [and not an expression(as with decltype)], it suddenly becomes an l-value.

One high-level way to think about lvalues and rvalues is that lvalues have names and can be assigned to.  `value` obviously has a name, so it shouldn't be surprising that it's an lvalue.

One way to think of `std::move()` or your static cast is that it not only casts its argument to the correct type, but it also produces an *rvalue expression*.

Thinking about your two functions `s` and `f`:

- Presumably, your function `s` takes an rvalue reference because you want to operate on *rvalues*, e.g. steal their resources with a move operation.
- In such a function, you might want to call functions on `value` that either (i) steal its resources, or (ii) treat it as an lvalue and do not steal its resources.
- The language lets you call `std::move()` for case (i), to tell `f` that `f` may steal resources.
- The language lets you pass `value` to functions without `std::move()`, as an lvalue, for case (ii), so you can call functions without worrying about that.  This might be desirable if you want `s` to steal resources later on.

This question is pretty similar:  [Rvalue Reference is Treated as an Lvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483250/rvalue-reference-is-treated-as-an-lvalue)

Comment: Ok, I see. I've never thought of type deduction as depending on the expression [and not the type of the expression]. I'll see if I can ingest it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The name of a variable used as an expression is always an lvalue, even if the variable's type is an rvalue reference. (Though `decltype` has some additional rules, not just looking at the expression's value category.) This is an intentional choice of the C++ language, because otherwise it would be too easy to accidentally move from a variable.

For example:

```
void debug_str_val(std::string var_name, std::string value);

void MyClass::set_name(const std::string& name)
{
    debug_str_val("name", name);
    m_name = name;
}

void MyClass::set_name(std::string&& name)
{
    debug_str_val("name", name);  // *
    m_name = std::move(name);
}
```

On the line marked with a `*`, `name` is treated as an lvalue, so `debug_str_val` gets a copy of the value. (It maybe could use `const std::string&` parameters instead, but it doesn't.)  If `name` were treated as an rvalue, the `debug_str_val` would be moved from, and then an unpredictable value would be assigned to `m_name`.

Once an object has a name, it could be used more than once, even if that name is an rvalue reference. So C++ uses it as an lvalue by default and lets the programmer say when they want it to be used as an rvalue, using `std::move`, or sometimes `std::forward`, or an explicit cast to rvalue reference type.