# C++11 recursive function using "&&" rvalue reference leads to compilation error

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, reference, rvalue

I tried to write some algorithm using recursive function and met this:

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
void f(vector<int>&& v) {
    if (!v.empty()) {
        // do some work
        v.pop_back();
        f(v); // compilation error!!!
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    f(vector<int>{1, 2, 3});//ok
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't compile, error message:

```
x86-64 clang 14.0.0
-std=c++11
<source>:7:9: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
        f(v);
        ^
<source>:3:6: note: candidate function not viable: expects an rvalue for 1st argument
void f(vector<int>&& v) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

The reason I used "&&" is that I hope it could receive some r-value input parameter and use it as reference(not copy). I also tried to change `f` into generic function:

```
template<typename T>
void f(vector<T>&& v) {
```

Still fails.

How to fix this?

Comment: A [rvalue reference is a lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483250/rvalue-reference-is-treated-as-an-lvalue), you need to use `f(std::move(v));`.

Comment: Inside `f`, `v` has a name and is therefore an l-value. Using `std::move(v)` will enable you to pass it recursivly to `f`.

Comment: This is probably the reduced essence of something else. (I know: MCVE. Thumbs up.) Nevertheless, I'm asking myself what you do with the moved `vector<int>`. It will be filled in the nested calls of `f()` but then lost as soon as the recursion is terminated... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced

```
template<typename T>
void f(vector<T>&& v) {
```

By

```
template<typename T> void f(T&& v)
```

In your case it's a `rvalue reference` and in the second case it's a `forwarding-reference` (sometime call `universal reference`)

Demo : https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZbvOoB0kcyYPVzlq

In the line

```
    f(v); // compilation error!!!
```

`v` is an `lvalue reference`, so you have 2 choices :

1. Transform it into a `rvalue reference` via an `std::move` like suggested in comment
2. Allow `f` to works with `lvalue reference`. This can be done with `forwarding-reference` like in my example or by adding an overload for `lvalue reference` : `void f(vector<int>& v)`. If you look at https://cppinsights.io/s/2f683e1c you will see that both code will do the same.

Comment: Why bother switching `typename` to `class`?

Comment: does the same, my brain is just wired to type `class`

Comment: I think this code generates two different versions of `f` and one of them receives an `lvalue`, it's not quite same to the question.

Comment: @Mer It indeed create 2 versions (https://cppinsights.io/s/2f683e1c) but it respect the wish of OP to not create copy. Both version use reference, one R the other L-value reference

Comment: @MartinMorterol Ok, maybe you're right, it's a recursive function, we don't need to pass `rvalue` all the time