# If I pass an rvalue into a function with T&&, in some cases I can change the value, in other cases I can't, why?

Tags: c++, forward, forwarding, perfect-forwarding

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void g(int&) {
    std::cout << "int&" << std::endl;
}

void g(int&&) {
    std::cout << "int&&" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void func(T&& x) {
    std::cout << "func(T&&)\n=================\n";
    std::cout << "int: " << std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int&: " << std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int&&: " << std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&&> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "=================\n";
    g(x);
    auto tmp = std::move(x);
    g(tmp);
    g(std::move(x));
}

int main() {
    func(2);
}
```

Output:

```
func(T&&)
=================
int: 0
int&: 0
int&&: 1
=================
int&
int&
int&&
```

Why does this code `int&&` overloading if I put `std::move()` inside of calling `g()` function?

I know, that I can solve this problem using `std::forward`, but I can't get why it doesn't work.

==================================================

**UPDATE:** Because of several answers, I have one more question:

In this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void foo(T&& bar){
    bar = T();
    std::cout << bar;
}

int main() {
    foo(22);    // OK
    foo("qwe");   // NOT OK
}
```

If I leave `foo(22)`, it works great, but it won't work if I leave `foo("qwe")`, why?

I tested a lot of cases.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483250/rvalue-reference-is-treated-as-an-lvalue

Comment: `x` has a name; its an lvalue. Thats why we need `std::forward`.

Comment: The `auto` in `auto tmp = std::move(x);` is `int`, not `int&` or `int&&` or something else. `g(tmp)` picks the lvalue overload for the exact same reason that `g(x)` does, even aside from the issues raised in Nathan Oliver's duplicate.

Comment: @NathanOliver
No, it doesn't.
This question is about universal references, but my question is about why universal reference choose that exact function overloading if universal reference is actually rvalue reference

Comment: `auto tmp = std::move(x);` the `tmp` is not an rvalue, it's an lvalue.

Comment: @NathanPierson
I've just tested. Replace auto->int&& and output hasn't changed

Comment: That's why I said "even aside from the issues raised in [the] duplicate".

Comment: Do a search for `reference collapse`.

Comment: @Eljay
Firstly, as I said, replace auto to int&& didn't affect
Secondly, why g(x) choose g(int&) overloading, but not the g(int&&) overloading

Comment: @MartinYork
I know how reference collapse works.
Check the code and output. X is `int&&`, because `std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&&>` returns `true`.

Comment: "_This question is about universal references,_": I don't see how. You are asking why the overloads of `g` are chosen, not how calling `func` behaves. `g` doesn't use any universal references. Nothing changes if you replace `T&&` with `int&&` and remove the template head.

Comment: Like many others, you are confusing concept of type and value category. These two are basically unrelated to each other. No matter the type, if you refer to variable by name, it's lvalue. You can have lvalue of type rvalue reference, there's absolutely no problem with that. `int&& var = 2;` is of type rvalue reference to int, but `var` is lvalue by itself.

Comment: Like an array collapse to a pointer. An r-value will collapse to an l-value at the drop of a hat. When you use x as a variable its type collapses to an l-value reference.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen
Did I understand you correctly?
In this case, when I call `func(2)`. I am creating `x` that is actually is `lvalue` but "contains" `rvalue reference`.
And when I am passing `x` into `g()` it choose `g(int&)` because `x` is `lvalue`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen
I added one subquestion into the post. Please check it

Comment: The `g(int&&)` overloading requires an rvalue (or xvalue).

Comment: *But It won't work if I leave foo("qwe")* `"qwe"` is c-string and it has the type `const char[4]`.  Arrays are not assignable so that's why `bar = T();` fails to compile.

Comment: Because a `&&` parameter in a **template** function is not an `&&` parameter in a non-template function.